# append jquery mobile textarea not expendable in multiline input

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, textarea

Im just added jQueryMobile on my project, and the auto expending textarea is rock. However, when i change my method, i append a textarea into a div, and the textarea not expending anymore. Do i miss out something or other code can help to solve this?

```
<div id="text"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#text").append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><textarea id="msg_input" cols="30" rows="1" name="textarea"></textarea></div>');
```

The textarea is display out, but not growing on next line.

Any help?

Steven

Comment: try giving height to the text area, as always there will be some limit to the text in the text area, so height can work.

Comment: @Sheetal, do you apply the textarea in jQueryMobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ready made plugin.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/